# c# how to read the message store on a windows mobile device 6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

can anyone post an example how to read the messagestore on a windows mobile device 6?
I done this with "InTheHand":

```
foreach (InTheHand.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.SmsMessage mess in sess.SmsAccount.SentItems)
                {
                    if (mess.Received.Year == thisYear && mess.Received.Month == thisMonth)
                    {
                        smsThisMonth++;
                    }
                }
```

The problem is, that I only have a evaluation version of InTheHand.
I would like to do this with OpenNetCF or mapidotnet, if possible.
But I didn't figure out how to do this with OpenNetCF and mapitdotnet isn't available anymore on the sourceforge site (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mapidotnet/).
I only found it on the svn directory, but there are no dlls.

Answer (score 1):

None of the OpenNETCF libraries provide this functionality.  We didn't bother trying to implement it because there already is an available solution (InTheHand's library) and [I don't like reinventing the wheel if there's a perfectly good one already available](http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2008/08/31/DevelopersUsingLibrariesIsNotASignOfWeakness.aspx).

If their price is too steep for you, you can always look at [this MSDN article on COM Interop in the CF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446497.aspx) and couple that with some of the [online tutorials on MAPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2007/03/21/getting-started-with-mapi.aspx) and [the MAPI documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842118.aspx).

[The MAPIDotNet project is probably worth investigation too](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=225535).  You say there are no binaries, but what does that matter?  You have a compiler.

MAPI is convoluted and confusing, even in C++.  From experience I can tell you that getting it all working in C# (I did it back in the 1.0 days before InTheHand had their product) takes at least a week and that's if you know how to work with COM and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out, how to do this with mapidotnet:

```
MAPI mapi = new MAPI();
IMAPIMsgStore[] stores = mapi.MessageStores;

        for (int i = 0; i < stores.Length; i++)
        {
            if (stores[i].DisplayName == @"SMS")
            {
                IMAPIFolder smsSentFolder = stores[i].SentMailFolder.OpenFolder();
                smsSentFolder.SortMessagesByDeliveryTime(TableSortOrder.TABLE_SORT_DESCEND);
                IMAPIMessage[] messages = smsSentFolder.GetNextMessages(999);
                for (int n = 0; n < messages.Length; n++)
                {
                    if (messages[n].LocalDeliveryTime.Month == monat && messages[n].LocalDeliveryTime.Year == jahr)
                    {
                        smsDiesenMonat++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I actually compiled the project, but I had a strange error, that I could not add the Mapilib.dll to my project.
But now I get it to work.